# jquery escape html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really a simple question. I tried to use jquery to insert html table rows. One of my rows has value with a subscript. So my question is what is the correct way to do this? Below is my broken code:

```
$('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="a" value="<sub>b</sub>" id="id_a"/></td>').appendTo('.leslie tr:last')
```

Thanks!

Comment: @canon Textarea won't render HTML.

Comment: There are several things that could be going wrong. In particular, your HTML code may be the problem. Also, as other have pointed out, are you sure you want to append an input box?

Comment: If that value is always going to be a subscript, why not just change the appearance with CSS?

Comment: can you visually show what you want to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input>` values do not support HTML tags.
This is completely impossible.

You could use `contentEditable` instead.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$('.leslie tr:last').html($('.leslie tr:last').html()+'<td><input type="text" size="5" name="a" id="id_a"/><sub>b</sub></td>')
```